# help solving circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

I'm looking for help solving this circuit.
what is the value of the resitor R4, knowing the Voltage between points A and B ( Vab=0,2V).
thanks

Comment: Is node B is connected to +5V ?

Comment: Such homework questions with no attempt at a solution are closed.

Comment: I don't really get how Vab becomes 0.2V!!

Comment: @nidhin there is a voltage drop in R3. Therefore the potential of B (relative to ground) is below 5V. Actually it will be below the potential in A by 0.2 V for some R4 value.

Comment: @RogerC. yup. got it. read something in schematic in a wrong way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is 200 ohm... 
Check the image below
[image]

Comment: If it is not possible to type the answer please rotate the image.

Comment: Rotated now... Tell if you can understand now ;)

Comment: In your equation you have \$V_{AB}=V_A-V_B=0.2 V\$ which is correct, but then you have a sign error isolating \$V_B\$ because \$V_B=-0.2+0.6 V\$ and not \$0.2+0.6\$.

Comment: oh... right, I'll fix it and edit the comment later. Thanks Roger

Comment: Fixed it... Again, sorry for the bad answer and thanks @RogerC.

Comment: Great, no problem!